# Unable to create a folder by executing a shell script using java

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder

I was trying to execute shell scripts using java code. The following is a sample code to demonstrate the issue :

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("/home/otaku/Programming/data/test1.sh");
try {

    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
    }

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    if (exitVal == 0) {
        System.out.println(output);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Script exited abnormally");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The shell script file *test1.sh* that I am trying to execute :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p -- teeh
echo 'Succesfully executed script'
```

I am getting echo message and was able to print in the java console indicating that the shell script is executed successfully. But no directory is being created even though the command **mkdir -p -- teeh** is executed. If I manually execute the script file using terminal it works like a charm. I would like to know the reason behind this and a possible solution to this as well.

Comment: Getting the echo message is no guarantee that the mkdir command worked. it just show that yous script was called and did run. I heavily suspect a writing permission. You should be aware of the technical user who is executing java / sh and provide him write rights.

Comment: You might also want to add a `pwd` to your shell script or a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to your Java class to make sure you're actually looking at the correct location. You shouldn't expect the `teeh` directory to be created inside `/home/otaku/Programming/data/` if you're not calling the java script from that location for instance.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for notifying the location change as java code is being used to execute the script and so it depends on where my project folder lies. If you could write an answer then I could mark it is the answer.

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI I have already made sure that it is not an issue with write permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir -p -- teeh
```

In this command the `teeh` path is a relative one rather than an absolute one: it will be created in the script's current working directory.

Your `bash` script is by default executed with the working directory of your JVM, which depends on where you executed your java application from. If you're executing your code from your IDE, by default this will be the project's root directory. If you're executing from the command line, it will be the directory you execute the `java` command from.

In any case you shouldn't expect a `/home/otaku/Programming/data/teeh` directory to be created by your current code unless you run the java application from the `/home/otaku/Programming/data/` directory.

There are many possible solutions, whose relevance depend on your context :

- execute your java code from the `/home/otaku/Programming/data/` directory
- use an absolute path in your `bash` script
- use `cd` in your `bash` script
- use `ProcessBuilder.directory(File dir)` to execute the `bash` script with the appropriate working directory